# Magento : I am not able to upload picture when I add product

Tags: magento

Error : Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.

I have tried cache clearing and it doesn't help for me.
I am using magento 1.8

Comment: There must be some extension using it. Please check all of Extensions regarding your Product images.

Answer (score 0):

just do below step as per link

http://mokamedia.ca/how-to-fix-image-type-and-information-needs-to-be-specified-for-each-store-view-in-magento-commerce/

Also try this

http://magentopaper.blogspot.in/2011/10/image-type-and-information-need-to-be.html

Try adding a php.ini file in your magento root directory and see whether it works:-

```
magic_quotes_gpc = off 
short_open_tag = on 
extension=pdo.so 
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

hope this will help you

Comment: sorry it din't .. read the problem properly rather than copying links from google.. I clearly asked for magento 1.8

Comment: there is no more difference with 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in 1.9.x using "[Dull uploader](https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader)" which removed the smart flash uploader in favor of a plain browser based file upload.

Answer (score -1):

Image type and information need to be specified for each store view:

1. Go to File structure root/media/ dhl
2. Cut or delete the “dhl” folder from there.
3. Clear cache from Admin Panel and now do upload the images
4. Hope, Its working good.

Comment: What is this "dhl" folder? I am having this issue and I do see a dhl folder there, but I'd like a little more information on what it is before doing so. I gave a -1 because no other info is provided.